# Excel - Need to compare two times in order

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I am using excel to compare two date columns that i need to compare. One is an Expiry time (SLA Expiry Time) and the other one is when it was actually updated (Initial SLA Contact Time).

It is to report on when a user takes a ticket to see if they are "Cherry Picking". So the result i am after is to see the order in which the tickets were actually updated as displayed below.

Note that 4th item was actually taken 8th in the list. This is what i am looking to identify.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the Contact Time is when someone started to work on a ticket, what you have numbered as 8 would actually be number 1. It was logged on 1/1. Even accounting for date formatting, it doesn't matter where in the world you are, 1/1 is earlier than 1/2 *and* 2/1.

Comment: I think you are trying to Order on the basic of FiFo (First Enter First Out) !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, but I have included a few different versions of the formula that you might want to use.

You can use the `RANK.EQ()` function to rank a list of cells based on an array of numbers. The Helper column in my example is there to show a numerical value for the time difference between when a job was Received and when that same job was Started. Higher numbers here indicate a longer time between Job Received and Job Started.

[image: Example spreadsheet of using RANK.EQ formula to rank Jobs based on start time]

Comment: that is prefect. It get's me the order i am looking for. Now I am using this as a data table in powerpivot. If i use a slicer, do you know this can update with the slicer filter?